# ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Session_Native' not found

Tags: php, session, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

My site had been worked like a charm since 2013 until yesterday, when this error occurred. I spent my whole day researching this error, but found nothing. Why is it happening?

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Session_Native' not found

[image]

Comment: Did you check for server changes like case-sensitive?

Comment: PHP does not throw `Exceptions` (especially not custom ones) on its own, catch the exception, gets its file and line number then update your question after you did some debugging.

Comment: Site created with Kohana framework

Comment: I'm running multiple sites with Kohana 3.3 and don't have this issue, so it must be something in your server environment that has changed. Maybe a recent PHP upgrade? Can you tell us more about the environment?

Comment: Is your server wonk under high pressure? - Check: max-open-files. Is your server use opt_cache? - restart it. Check is files contains right clases. And file names are case-sensitive.